# How does a ping to a public IP work in my same AS?

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, isp

I am an ISP, I have a BGP session established with a larger provider. The question is, when from my network I ping a public IP, also inside my AS, Does the ping go to my provider and then come back, Or does the routing happen inside my network?

Comment: A packet is sent to a destination address, and that gets routed to the destination network, on your network or otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, traffic to addresses within your network should never go via your upstream ISP. Routers in your network should have a route for the every IP prefix in your network and exchange those via iBGP.

In addition, it's good practice to never accept routes towards (more specifics) of your own IP prefixes from your upstreams, since you should always be the one originating those prefixes. If you receive them from your upstreams, it could indicate a BGP hijack and accepting the more specific could result in (even more) damage within your network.

Answer (score 1):

All ICMP packets destined for prefixes inside your AS should not go out off your AS. iBGP routes within your AS are advertised within your AS so logically there is no need to route outside your AS.